# Regex to remove titles from Name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a JS regex to clean names from titles. E.g.

```
Dr. Ian Smith => Ian Smith
Prof. Dr.  Ian Smith => Ian Smith
Ian Smith, Phd => Ian Smith
Dr. Ian S. => Ian S.
```

The rules are:
remove everything after the last comma
remove everything before the first word, that has no fullstop.

I currently have this to get the part after the last comma:

```
^.*,\s*(.*)$
```

However it omits the comma as such. For the first part - i.e. getting getting everything uptil the first word without fullstop - I have no idea.

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far if you want help debugging.

Comment: sorry, please see my edited answer.

Comment: Just a caution about using the fullstop as a delimiter, depending on your target audience. In English, the full stop is not required if the abbreviation ends in the same letter as the abbreviated word (e.g. Mr, Mrs, Dr but "Prof." still has it). American English seems to always have it. See paragraph 5 of http://m.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/capsandabbr/abbr, and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/is-it-proper-to-omit-periods-after-honorifics-mr-mrs-dr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(\w{2,}+\.( ){1,})|(, \w+)
```

Based on the examples you gave me, this regex works.

It now depends on the language in which you have to use it, I'll give you some examples.

Javascript:

```
const regex = /(\w{2,}+\.( ){1,})|(, \w+)/g;
const str = `Dr. Ian Smith
Prof. Dr.  Ian Smith
Ian Smith, Phd
Dr. Ian S.`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\w{2,}+\\.( ){1,})|(, \\w+)";
final String string = "Dr. Ian Smith\n"
     + "Prof. Dr.  Ian Smith\n"
     + "Ian Smith, Phd\n"
     + "Dr. Ian S.";
final String subst = "";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Python:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\w{2,}+\.( ){1,})|(, \w+)"

test_str = ("Dr. Ian Smith\n"
    "Prof. Dr.  Ian Smith\n"
    "Ian Smith, Phd\n"
    "Dr. Ian S.")

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

And so on. Hope this help.

Comment: Is the `+` on `\w{2,}` required?
`/(\w{2,}\.( ){1,})|(, \w+)/g` works nicely, and resolves the _Nothing to repeat_ error on the JS example.

Comment: Just make sure you don't run a **"lastName, firstName"** thru this regex ;)

Answer (score 3):

One way to go about this could be to list the titles you want to match using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and replace the matches with an empty string. You can adjust the regex to your requirements.

[`\b(?:Prof\.? *|Dr\. *|, Phd)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bsn4SA/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "Dr. Ian Smith",
  "Prof. Dr.  Ian Smith",
  "Ian Smith, Phd",
  "Dr. Ian S.",
  "Prof Dr. Ian Smith"
];
let pattern = /\b(?:Prof\.? *|Dr\. *|, Phd)\b/g;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + s.replace(pattern, ""));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[`\w+\. *(?=\w+)|,[\s\w]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/g0Y6xX/3)

This is split in two parts. The first part (`\w+\. *(?=\w+)`) will match text before the first word with no full stop. The second part (`,[\s\w]*$`) will match from the last comma until the end of the line (`$`).

Alternatively you can do:

[`^(\w+\.\s*)+|,[\s\w]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/g0Y6xX/3)

which produces same results than previous regex but is faster (requires less steps).

Edit: to also match lines like `Prof Dr.`:

```
^.*?(?=\b\w+ )|,[\s\w]*$
```

Comment: this does not work for `Prof Dr. Ian Smith`. It only works for abbreviations with a dot.